How to run git fetch on a private branch from within Github Actions
In a GitHub Actions workflow, I'm trying to synchronize/push the changes from my local branch to a remote, private branch; however, I am receiving the following error in GitHub Actions:

remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/my-github-username/my-remote-repository.git/' not found

(Replaced my username and repository just for demonstration purposes.)
Here's my GitHub Actions workflow:
name: Sync changes with remote private repo

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  sync_with_remote_repo:
    runs-on: self-hosted
      - name: Push dev changes to the my-remote-repository repository
        run: |
          git remote add my-remote-repository https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.MY_PAT }}@github.com/my-github-username/my-remote-repository.git
          git fetch my-remote-repository main
          git push my-remote-repository HEAD:main

When I run this command manually via any CLI (including a new VM), it works perfectly fine, so I know my credentials are working OK and isn't being mixed up with any other credentials I have on my system.
I tried even picking up where the workflow left off on the self-hosted GitHub runner, by running the same git fetch command, and it worked perfectly fine. Just not sure why it's not working when the workflow is firing off.
Here's what I noticed that is in my .git/config file, which looks fine to me.
[remote "my-remote-repository"]
        url = https://x-access-token:MY_PAT@github.com/my-github-username/my-remote-repository.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/my-remote-repository/*

What can I try to resolve this?

How have you confirmed secrets.MY_PAT?

How are you calling this action? Is this a reusable workflow or a forked repository?

Yep. Whenever I check the .git/config file, it shows the value of secrets.MY_PAT was added with the URL for the remote repository. In other words, it looks like x-access-token:. I'm calling the workflow action by pushing changes to the main branch of my repository.
